# OOM error on Java HotSpot but runs fine on OpenJDK

Tags: garbage-collection, out-of-memory, java, jvm-hotspot

Trying to reach out to see if there is any known difference that may be causing this.

The application was developed and runs fine under:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
```

And its currently running in production environment under

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

and occasionally fails due to -

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Any help would be appreciated to solve this problem.

Comment: it depends on many things. For example: which gc do you use? how much memory is allocated to the application? how is memory usage under production different than in dev environment? - was the app tested under exactly same conditions on both jvms?
Maybe there are some memory leaks that manifested only on production machine?
If I understand correctly, your error means GC is taking most of the CPU time of the process while recovering almost no memory.

Comment: OpenJDK and Oracle both use the same JVM - HotSpot.

Comment: yes test environment has same memory allocation and we are using default garbage collection settings at this time, without any customization.

Comment: @Mark1234 Take a thread dump of each and see what the difference is.

Comment: ok, I notice that its caused by usage of a particular library and not consistent.

Comment: Is the OpenJDK version also 64-bit? --- If it runs fine on 151, and fails on 45, why not upgrade production to 151?

Comment: yes both 64 bit,and its not trivial to upgrade the version.